# Best way to use a placeholder image and then replace it after the image finishes loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently the google static maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview takes too long to load which causes a high LCP(large content painting).

The solution would be to load a placeholder image and then once the google static maps IMG is finished loading to replace the placeholder with it. What would be a way to implement this?

I did try this but it didn't replace the placeholder and always returned false.

```
function imgLoaded(imgElement) {
  return imgElement.complete && imgElement.naturalHeight !== 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but effective solution is to use the `onLoad` event to update a state and toggle the placeholder visibility, like so:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const LOADING_GIF_URL = `https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnzy.gif`;
const LARGE_IMAGE_URL = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg`;

export default function App() {
  
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        !imageLoaded ?
          <img alt="Loading" src={LOADING_GIF_URL} style={{ width: `50px` }} />
        :
          `Clear your cache and refresh the page to reload the image`
      }

      <img
        alt="Large pic"
        src={LARGE_IMAGE_URL}
        style={imageLoaded ? {} : { display: `none` }}
        onLoad={() => setImageLoaded(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[See this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-72794898-p32zdm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I saw this solution too and you're right it will probably be the most simple and effective. I will try it out and see

Comment: It works but it has the issue where it shows both images before hiding the placeholder which doesn't look too great. Is there a way to make that not happen? I understand it's due to the state change which causes that.

Comment: @steven5210 I couldn't reproduce this issue in my tests, would you mind sharing a reproduceable codesandbox, or perhaps record a gif?

Comment: it looks like it does work properly but has to be done on the <img> element like your example. I had it on the parent div and I guess that caused it to flash. Thanks!